# Organizing the Navigation Menu

Tags: urls, navigation

I have a problem with menu organization. I have a Pages with url "pressroom" and have a Category with the same name. I want to make it a one menu item.

**Pressroom** `(sitename.com/pressroom/)`

- **page 1** `(sitename.com/pressroom/page1/)`
- **page 2** `(sitename.com/pressroom/page2/)`
- **category with posts** `(sitename.com/category/pressroom/news/)`

When I am in Category - nav_menu parent item have a correct css selector `current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent`, but when I am go to post of this category (url changed to `sitename.com/pressroom/news/postid/`) - css selector of parent menu item disappear.

How can I correct this?

Comment: I don't understand. You want the menu items to treat categories like "parents" of the posts? Categories are not "parents" of posts, why would they have a selector identifying them as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check nav menu target URL for '/pressroom/', then check if it's a post. If it fits, add custom class to that menu item.

```
<?php
function my_add_posts_page_ancestor_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if( false !== strpos($item->url, '/pressroom/')
    && is_single($item->ID)
    && !is_page($item->ID) ) {
        $classes[] = 'my-ancestor-class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_add_posts_page_ancestor_class', 10, 2);
```

The code is untested and can be improved. It's a direction to think about.

**Update**

See what I've found: [Add a class to wp_nav_menu() items with URLs included in the current URL](http://www.rarescosma.com/2010/11/add-a-class-to-wp_nav_menu-items-with-urls-included-in-the-current-url/)